# Unable to push to an array that is inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to push some stuff into an array that lives inside my object. The thing is it runs, but when I view the object, the array remains empty even though I push into.

```
function add(){
    addItem = prompt("Where would you like to add this item to?")

    kitchen.forEach(function(item){
        if (addItem == item.belongsTo["fruits"]) {
            itemAdded = prompt("What would you like to add?");
            item.items[0].push(itemAdded);
        }else if(addItem == item.belongsTo["veggies"]){
            itemAdded = prompt("What would you like to add?");
            item.items[1].push(itemAdded);
        }
    });
}

function showKitchen(){
    kitchen.forEach(function(list){
        console.log(list);
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like knowing what `kitchen` is would be pretty important to understanding this problem. Maybe you could post that?

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: var kitchen = [
    {
        belongsTo: "fruits",
        items: []
    },
    {
        belongsTo: "veggies",
        items: []   
    }
]

Comment: You are trying to push into `item.items[1]`. Is `item.items` and an array of arrays?

Comment: Well, technically I have two arrays. One belongs to kitchen and the other belongs to veggies.

Comment: You have other logic problems also :   `item.belongsTo["fruits"]` is looking for an object property on a string. Should be throwing error....check your console

Comment: surprisingly it isn't. I thought it would, but it isn't

Comment: Ok...but will still always be undefined

Comment: Yea, I need help to figure out how to make this work

Comment: `item.items[1]` is not an array. I would recommend you to restructure your `kitchen` object to a `dictionary(object)` instead of `array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restructured the `kitchen` object so that you don't need to loop every time to add an item.

```js
// persist items with count
const kitchen = {
  fruits: {},
  veggies: {}
};

function addItemToKitchen() {
  const group = prompt("Where would you like to add this item to?");
  if (group) {
    const itemToAdd = prompt(`What would you like to add in kitchen(${group}?`);

    if (itemToAdd) {
      // pick the group if found or create one
      kitchen[group] = kitchen[group] || {};
      // add item to group
      kitchen[group][itemToAdd] = (kitchen[group][itemToAdd] || 0) + 1;

      showKitchen();
    }
  }
}

function showKitchen() {
  Object.entries(kitchen).forEach(([group, items]) => {
    console.log(group, ':');
    Object.entries(items).forEach(([item, count]) => {
      console.log(`\t${item}(${count})`);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addItemToKitchen()">Add Item</button>
<button onclick="showKitchen()">Show Kitchen List</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var kitchen = [ 
    { belongsTo: "fruits", items: [] },
    { belongsTo: "veggies", items: [] } 
    ]
    
  function add(){
    var addItem = prompt("Where would you like to add this item to?");
    if(addItem == "fruits"){
      var item = prompt("What would you like to add?");
      kitchen[0].items.push(item);
    }
    else if(addItem == "veggies"){
      var item = prompt("What would you like to add?");
      kitchen[1].items.push(item);
    }
    // console.log(kitchen);
    showKitchen();
  };

  function showKitchen(){
    kitchen.forEach(function(list){
        console.log(list);
    });
}
add();
```